# Oracle - Error: 'ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration, notnull, ora-01400

I'm trying to insert a record into a table, but getting the error -

> 'ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (....'. The table structure is:

I migrate from Mysql to Oracle.

On Mysql this works, but on Oracle it is not working. How can I fix this? Do I need write all column insert query or unselect not null option

Comment: MySQL lets you insert null into not-null columns (and silently converts that to something else). Oracle actually obeys your constraint that you do not want to store NULLs in that columns. The solution is to provide a value instead of NULL when inserting.

Comment: there's a NOT NULL constraint on certain column(s), so you need to either provide a value during insert, or perhaps a trigger is missing (which can populate a column from a sequence for example)

Comment: Ok. How can i drop 'not null' option on Oracle all tables?

Comment: You can write a script using data from all_tab_cols altering columns to be nullable, but are you sure you want that ? why not use `NVL` ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, does it let you insert nulls always, or is it only the way it works with empty strings as [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3148/1) which is not like in oracle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c336c/1)

Comment: @A.B.Cade: MySQL will let you update/insert `NULL` into a not-null column, but will silently change that to an empty string or 0 (this depends on the configuration. I don't recall which mode this is, but AFAIK this was the default behaviour in older versions). MySQL does distinguish between NULL and an empty string (unlike Oracle)

Comment: i am not sure because we use Mysql and PHP our system. I don't edit my php code because very big. What can i do? edit code or drop not null parameter

Comment: @neoerol, if you drop the constraint it'll work, but you'll have a DB which isn't exactly what you need, for example, if you expect an empty string in a not null column, you might find there a "real" null instead...

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that oracle RDBMS considers empty string null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create or replace trigger EDITIONS_COR
  before insert or update on EDITIONS
  for each row
begin
  if INSERTING then
    select EDITIONS_SEQ.nextval into :new.ID from DUAL;
  end if;
  :new.CORDATE:=SYSDATE;
  :new.USERNAME:=USER;
end;
```