# Error ORA-01400 when migrating from MySQL Database through sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

we followed this [instruction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/mysql-093223.html) for migrating mysql to oracle,at the last step, we hit the following error:Migration actions have failed, check the migtation reports for details: capture Classic capture ora-01400: cannot insert null into ("MIGRATION_REPO","MD_PROJECTS","ID")

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle - Error: 'ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247335/oracle-error-ora-01400-cannot-insert-null-into)

Comment: Provide a value instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Our mysql is quite simple, create a database and create only one table: mysql> create table name (id char(20), name char(20)); Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec) , then migrate mysql to oracle and press finish->error ora-01400 , we don't even have any trigger or procedure on mysql , any more advice would be appreciated.